# Local database to online database

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have local database with a lot of data for developing a site...now I want to publish this project.
I wanna know. how Can I bring this data from local to online database?

Comment: Get some cloud database server make a backup of your local data and restore it on the cloud one

Comment: Normally the data that exists in local machine is not valid and just for test; in this case you can generate an script of database schema and execute it in production server. But if you want the the data too; then back it up then restore in production server

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you haven't specified database, tools, the answer can be extraordinary as well.

Let's imagine that you have local MS SQL DB and Azure SQL db.

There is not a standard method how to do this.
Right click on the database. Generate scripts.
Then select all objects that you need
then go to advanced and change types of data to script to:Scheme and data

as the result you will have full damp of your database that you have to run on AZURE SQL.

[image]

ps. more ideas only if you provide more details

Answer (score 0):

That I usually use is Azure and you can publish you app and database to it direct from VS. Of course you can do is separate  db or app.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/deploying-applications-services-and-components-resources?view=vs-2022